# Perl how to remove second line of a string

Tags: regex, perl

Perl how to remove second line of a string ?

i can remove the first line using this code:

```
$cpusttp =~ s/^(.*\n){1}//;
```

Comment: I don't think you should be trying to extract lines form the middle of a multi-line string. Where did this string come from? If you've read it from a file then it's probably best to read it into an array instead. The, removing the second line comes down to just `splice @data, 1, 1`. If you explain more about what you are doing then we will be able to help you better

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of ways to do this:

```
my $multi_line_string = 'line1
line2
line3
line 4
fifth line';

#regex matches once - second line is the first thing after a linefeed
#\n so it'll remove the second line. 
#This wouldn't scale well to removing the 4th line though. 
my ($new_string) = $multi_line_string =~ s/\n(.*\n)/\n/r;
print $new_string;
```

or perhaps:

```
my @things = split ( "\n", $multi_line_string );
print join ("\n", @things[0,2..$#things] );
```

Or with splice:

```
my $line_to_delete = 1; #arrays start at 0
my @things = split ( "\n", $multi_line_string );
splice ( @things, $line_to_delete, 1);
print join ( "\n", @things);
```

Comment: thanks, but where i say is the second line on the frist code ?

Comment: By default, regular expressions only match once. The second line is the first line _after_ a linefeed ( `\n` ) which is why it works. (Add a `/g` regex modifier and it'll delete every other line!). I don't think it makes a good general solution (delete line N) which is why I'd suggest split/join if you want to delete the 85th line or similar.

Comment: thanks a lot, found the solution for me $cpusfinal = join ("\n", @cpufinal[0,4..8] );

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `{1}`. Anything will be repeated exactly once, unless otherwise specified.

Also, I don't think regex is the right tool for the job. However, this should do:

```
$cpusttp =~ s/^(.*\n)\K(.*\n)//;
```

The idea is to match the first line, then ignore it (`\K`), then match another line.

Comment: thanks, but i didn't understood, and what is the other way ?

Comment: @GabrielSousa, `split`/`join` looks way better to me. Sobrique's answer gives an example.